# Media player that will remember my last position

Tags: windows, media-player

I'm currently using Windows Media Player for watching DVDs. Unfortunately if I close the player, I lose my position. My main requirement is that I want a player that will remember my position, even if I restart the computer or accidentally eject the DVD.

I tried [VLC player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html), but sometimes it fails to open DVDs (don't know why).

Other requirements:

- Runs on Windows
- Full-screen mode
- Ability to show DVD menus (so that I don't have to guess which one of twenty tracks to play)

Nice features to have:

- Quickly jump back 30 seconds
- Ability to skip time-wasting piracy warnings, etc.

Comment: Personally, I've used Media Player Classic (MPC) klite package which can remembers last position of the video, last window size/location. I've not used it with DVD though therefore I cannot add this as an answer.

Comment: VLC should handle this, it sounds like you may have unidentified / unresolved system issues.

Comment: @Casebash Checkout http://kantaris.org/ i've never used it for DVD playback but am sure it will meet your needs.

Comment: @Casebash http://www.splayer.org/index.en.html may also suit your requirements nicely.

Comment: @Caleb I doubt VLC has the feature of remembering the last position.

Comment: Just downloaded the latest Windows VLC Player "2.1.3 Rincewind" and it does not have that option. The Android beta versie *does* remember the position.

Comment: VLC actually have add on to remember last position (add on s available for Windows and Linux machines)

Comment: Use [KMPlayer](http://www.kmplayer.com/) it's SUPERB!!

Answer (score 15):

I recommend [media player classic](http://mpc-hc.org/) which is available with [klite codec package](http://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm) almost every day (*I've not used it with dvd though*) and it's one of the best media player applications I've ever used. This nice application can remember almost everything include

- Last window size
- Last video position for each video you played. Note that it also remembers the last video played even after you restart your pc. You can simply open MPC and click play <kbd>►</kbd> and it will automatically open the last video with same time it was closed at.
- As for DVD, there is an option to remember the last position as well.
  [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/410892) on SU explain how to set it up.
- For skipping video, it can be done by hitting
  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> to skip forward
  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> to skip backward.

---

This is how the player looks like:

[image: Media Player Classis UI]

---

Right click menu:

[image: Right Click Menu]

---

Options menu:

[image: Options Menu]

Comment: Worth mentioning the MPC remembers the last position of every file that was played on it not just the last one. MPC surely does wonders.

Comment: It was there before (last video position per video) But guess i removed it when I added the remember after restart part. I emphasized on that part now. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

[SMPlayer](http://smplayer.sourceforge.net/)

- remembers the settings of all files you play. So you start to watch a movie but you have to leave, when you open that movie again it will be resumed at the same point you left it, and with the same settings: audio track, subtitles, volume even after restart,
- it runs on windows,
- has a configurable screen (4:3,16:9, stretched, full etc)
- don't know about DVD menus,
- jumps backs 10sec or 1min with one key, which is useful for skipping the piracy warnings
- another thing is it can be used to manage the timing of subtitles based on text if you find setting the lag in time to be annoying.

I have used it as a default player for more than 4 years.

Answer (score 6):

Before I switched on Linux, I used [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) and [BSplayer](http://www.bsplayer.com/). Both are good media players but since you seem to have issues with VLC you may try BSplayer.
Bsplayer has a free and paid version. Paid version is quite expensive (29.90 EUR for a new licence at the moment and 19.90 EUR if renewing a licence). 
In BSplayer, for seeing DVD menus, you will need a paid version, free version recognises only .vob files and does not read DVD menus.

**Your requirements**

- Option to remember video position is available under general
  preferences
- Runs on windows
- Full-screen mode available
- DVD menus available but only on paid version

**Other features**

- Jump back and forward (keyboard shortcuts <kbd>.</kbd> 10 sec
  forward, <kbd>,</kbd> 10 sec back)
- Paid version has an option to skip the warning on beginning but in my
  experience it wasn’t always working properly thus the jumping forward
  option is handy
- Automated subtitles download, additionally paid version includes a
  good subtitle editor too
- Capture video screen and save it to .jpeg (frame capturing)
- YouTube streaming

Note that I’m no longer using windows or BSplayer and in my opinion, VLC is superior and offer better codec's support, so I would recommend to dig in VLC prior you ditch it since all your requirements are available in VLC too. Non-reading DVD's could be easily just a missing codec

Answer (score 2):

Just use `mpv`
for me on ubuntu
`sudo apt install mpv`
And also install on windows by using chocolaty-package-manager

then
`mpv --save-position-on-quit *`
This save all position for all file by obtaining md5
or quit it while pressing `Shift` + `q` to do the same action

Comment: also without that parameter, using 'q' will quit without saving, and using 'Q' will quit saving position